# Trying to insert value which should be populated dynamically from select statemnt

Tags: mysql

```
INSERT INTO EMAIL_CAMP_TABLE (EMAIL_ID,FLAG) 
VALUES ( (
 SELECT DISTINCT (UPT.EMAIL_ID) 
 FROM ITEM_MASTER_TABLE IMT 
 INNER JOIN ORDER_DETAIL_TABLE ODT ON IMT.ITEM_ID = ODT.ITEM_ID 
 INNER JOIN ORDER_MASTER_TABLE OMT ON ODT.ORDER_ID = OMT.ORDER_ID 
 INNER JOIN PAYMENT_TRANSACTION_TABLE PT ON OMT.ORDER_ID = PT.ORDER_ID
 INNER JOIN USER_PROFILE_TABLE UPT ON OMT.USER_ID = UPT.USER_ID 
 WHERE T.COUPON_CODE = 'ABCD'), 'N')
```

I tried with the above query,which works fine if the select statement returns one value. If select returns more than one row, then i am getting an error: Subquery returns more than 1 row. How do i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `insert . . . select`.  You don't need `values`:

```
INSERT INTO EMAIL_CAMP_TABLE (EMAIL_ID, FLAG) 
     SELECT DISTINCT UPT.EMAIL_ID, 'N' 
     FROM ITEM_MASTER_TABLE IMT 
     INNER JOIN ORDER_DETAIL_TABLE ODT ON IMT.ITEM_ID = ODT.ITEM_ID 
     INNER JOIN ORDER_MASTER_TABLE OMT ON ODT.ORDER_ID = OMT.ORDER_ID 
     INNER JOIN PAYMENT_TRANSACTION_TABLE PT ON OMT.ORDER_ID = PT.ORDER_ID
     INNER JOIN USER_PROFILE_TABLE UPT ON OMT.USER_ID = UPT.USER_ID 
     WHERE T.COUPON_CODE = 'ABCD';
```